# Error installing Solr with Sitecore

Tags: solr, sitecore

I am working on a new site being built on Sitecore 8.0 rev. 150223 and I am trying to install Solr 6.2.0.0. I have mainly followed the instructions here: https://born4joy.wordpress.com/2015/09/03/installation-and-configuration-of-solr-for-sitecore-8/ (I am new to this process and Sitecore itself)

I have completed the steps in the instructions but I am getting the below server error. I cannot find any similar instances in googling about this issue.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Field type 'alphaOnlySort' not found

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrNetException: Field type 'alphaOnlySort' not found

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[SolrNetException: Field type 'alphaOnlySort' not found]
   SolrNet.Schema.SolrSchemaParser.Parse(XDocument solrSchemaXml) +1091
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex.Initialize() +914
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrContentSearchManager.Initialize() +169

[HttpException (0x80004005): Field type 'alphaOnlySort' not found]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +544
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +186
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +402
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +343

[HttpException (0x80004005): Field type 'alphaOnlySort' not found]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +579
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +112
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +716
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the fieldType for alphaOnlySort. Try adding below definition to your **schema.xml** file

```xml
<fieldType name="alphaOnlySort" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
  <analyzer>
    <!-- KeywordTokenizer does no actual tokenizing, so the entire
         input string is preserved as a single token
      -->
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
    <!-- The LowerCase TokenFilter does what you expect, which can be
         when you want your sorting to be case insensitive
      -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <!-- The TrimFilter removes any leading or trailing whitespace -->
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
    <!-- The PatternReplaceFilter gives you the flexibility to use
         Java Regular expression to replace any sequence of characters
         matching a pattern with an arbitrary replacement string, 
         which may include back references to portions of the original
         string matched by the pattern.

         See the Java Regular Expression documentation for more
         information on pattern and replacement string syntax.

         http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html
      -->
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^a-z])" replacement="" replace="all" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Thank you! That definitely should have been obvious, but with my current knowledge I wouldn't have known where that was missing from. (Strange that that isn't included by default in that file!)